# i want to calculate the sum of day's hours by using angularjs

Tags: angularjs-scope

***// ***my jsp*** //***

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Route</button><button class="btn btn-default pull-right"ng-click="saveTimeentryData(timesheet)">save</button></h3>

<td><input type="text" class="timetext" ng-model="timesheet.Mon" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="timetext" ng-model="timesheet.Tue" > <br><br> 
                <td><input type="text" class="timetext"ng-model="timesheet.Wed" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="timetext" ng-model="timesheet.Thu" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="timetext" ng-nodel="timesheet.Fri"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="timetext" ng-model="timesheet.Sat"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="timetext" ng-model="timesheet.Sun"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="timetext" ng-model="timesheet.Total"></td></tr> 
                      </tbody>
```

**// angularcontroller page//**

```
$scope.saveTimeentryData = function(Obj) {
        console.log(Obj);
        return;



      if (Obj == undefined || Obj == "") {
       showAlert.message("Warning","Time Entry should not be empty.");
       return;

      } else if (Obj.hours <= "8"
        || Obj.hours == undefined) {
       showAlert
         .message("Warning",
           "Time Entry should not be lessthan '8' or 'empty'.");
       return;
      } else if (Obj.hours <= "40"
        || Obj.hours == undefined) {
       showAlert
         .message("Warning",
           "Time Entry should not be lessthan 40 hours.");
       return;
      }

      var promise = timeentryService
        .saveTimeentryData(Obj);
      promise.then(function(results) {
       if (results.data.code == 0) {
        showAlert.message("Warning",
          results.data.message);
       } else {
        showAlert.message("Success",
          results.data.message);
        $scope.getTime("TimeEntry");
       }
      }, function(reason) {
       alert('Failed: ' + reason);
      });
     };
```

the above is for the controller in angularjs

***//this is to get the angular service from the controller page//***

```
this.saveTimeentryData = function(Obj){

         var URL = null; 
      if(Obj.id != "" && Obj.id != undefined){
       URL = appConfigUrl.masterURL+'/timeentry/update';
      }else{
       Obj.isActive = true;
       Obj.id = "";
       URL = appConfigUrl.masterURL+'/timeentry/insert';
      }

      $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
      var promise=$http.post(URL,Obj)
      .success(function(results, status, headers, config) {  

       Obj.itemName = "";
       Obj.itemValue = "";
       Obj.id = "";
       return results;
      })
      .error(function(results, status, headers, config) {
       console.log('Error: ', results, status, headers, config);

      });
      return promise;
        };
```

here I sent everything that i've been working.

Comment: i need to calculate the total hours of each day